# Directional derivative of risk measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, finance, gateaux-derivative, risk-assessment

Let $S,Z \in L^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $\rho \colon L^\infty \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a risk measure. When is the directional derivative (Gâteaux derivative) 
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\rho(Z + \epsilon S) - \rho(Z)}{\varepsilon}$$ existing? How is it linked to the coherency of a risk measure?
As an example, can we compute the directional derivative of the expected shortfall
$$\mathrm{ES}_\alpha(X) = \frac{1}{(1-\alpha)} \int_\alpha^1 F^{-1}_X(p) \mathrm{d}p \quad ?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\<}{\langle}\newcommand{\>}{\rangle}\renewcommand{\Re}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\ES}{\mathrm{ES}}$This is a very interesting question and the answer is affirmative under certain conditions. We may actually show that coherent continuous risk measures are [*Hadamard* differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_derivative) (which is stronger than [Gâteaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_derivative) differentiability)

**About differentiability of risk measures.** Let $\mathcal{Z}=\mathcal{L}_p(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathrm{P})$ and let $F:\mathcal{Z}\to\Re\cup \{+\infty\}$ be a convex extended-real-valued mapping. Recall that the [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate) of $F$ is the function $F^*:\mathcal{Z}^*\to\Re\cup \{+\infty\}$ defined as $$F^*(Y) = \sup_{Z\in\mathcal{Z}} \{\< Y,Z \> - F(Z)\}$$ and similarly we define the function $F^{**}:\mathcal{Z}^{**}\to\Re$.

Let us also recall that the subgradient of $F$ at a point $X_0\in\mathcal{Z}$ is the set

$$
\partial F(X_0)=\{Y\in\mathcal{Z}^*: F(X) - F(X_0) \geq \< Y, X-X_0\>, \forall X\in\mathcal{Z}\}.
$$

Then, by the conjugate subgradient theorem applied to $F^{**}$ we have that for $X$ such that $F^{**}(X)$ is finite we have
$$
\partial F^{**}(X) = \arg\max \{ Y\in \mathcal{Z}^{*}: \<Y,X\> - F^*(X)\}.\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
$$
If $\rho:\mathcal{Z}\to\Re\cup\{+\infty\}$ is a lower semicontinuous coherent risk measure (such as the expected shortfall you mentioned), then $\rho = \rho^*$, so by \eqref{eq:1} we have
$$
\partial \rho(X) = \partial \rho^{**}(X) = \arg\max \{ Y\in \mathcal{Z}^{*}: \<Y,X\> - \rho^*(X)\},\tag{2}\label{eq:2}
$$
for $X\in\mathrm{dom}\rho = \{X\in\mathcal{Z}: \rho(X) < \infty\}$.

Using that fact that coherent risk measures are written as

$$
\rho(X) = \sup_{Y\in\mathfrak{W}}\< Y,X\>,
$$

for some convex w*-closed set $\mathfrak{W}\subseteq \mathcal{Z}^*$, we may see that the subgradient of $\rho$ at $X$ - following \eqref{eq:2} - can be written as

$$
\partial \rho(X) = \arg\max_{Y\in\mathfrak{W}}\<Y, X\>.
$$
Let us now recall the definition of the [Hadamard directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_derivative) which is defined for $F:\mathcal{Z}\to\Re\cup\{+\infty\}$ as follows

$$
F'(X;D_0)=\lim_{t\downarrow 0, D\to D_0} \frac{F(X+tD)-F(X)}{t}.
$$

If a function $F:\mathcal{Z}\to\Re\cup\{+\infty\}$ is Hadamard directionally differentiable at $X$ along a direction $D$, then it is also Gâteaux directionally differentiable and the two derivatives coincide.

Furthermore, we know that if a convex mapping $F:\mathcal{Z}\to\Re\cup\{+\infty\}$ is finite-valued at $X$ and continuous at $X$, then $F$ is also subdifferentiable at $F$, $\partial F(X)$ is nonempty, convex, bounded and w*-compact and $F$ is Hadamard-diferentiable at $X$ with

$$
F'(X;D) = \sup_{Y\in\partial F(X)}\< Y, D\>.
$$

**Differentiability of the expected shortfall.** The expected shortfall $\ES_\alpha:\mathcal{Z}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ can be written in the following dual representation

$$
\ES_{\alpha}[X] = \sup_{Y\in\mathfrak{A}_\alpha}\< Y, X\>
$$

where

$$
\mathfrak{A}_\alpha = \{
 Y\in\mathcal{Z}^*: \mathbb{E}[Y]=1, Y\in [0,\alpha^{-1}] \text{ a.s.}
\}
$$
The expected shortfall is subdifferentiable with
  \begin{align*}
   \partial(\ES_{\alpha})[Z] &= \arg\max_{Y\in\mathfrak{A}}   \<Y,Z\>  \\
        &= \arg\max_{Y\in\mathcal{Z}^*}  \left\{ \<Y,Z\>: Y\in [0,\alpha^{-1}], \text{a.e. }, \mathbb{E}[Y]=1  \right\}.
  \end{align*}

To further proceed, let us assume that $X$ is a random variable described by a continuous cumulative probability function $H_X$ and define $t^*$ to be
$$
t^* = \inf\{t: H_X(t)\geq 1-\alpha\},
$$
and further assume that $\{t: H_X(t) = 1-\alpha\}$ is a singleton for a given $\alpha$.

*Interpretation*: the expected shortfall is equivalently written as 
$$\ES_\alpha(X) = \inf\{t\in\Re: \phi(t):=t+\mathbb{E}[X-t]_+\}.$$Then, $\phi$ attains its minimum at $t^*$.

Relaxing the equality constraint $\mathbb{E}[Y]=1$ we have the Lagrangian
  \begin{align*}
   L(Y,\lambda; Z) &= \<Y, Z\> + \lambda(1-\mathbb{E} [Y])\\
                   &= \<Y, Z\> + \lambda - \<\lambda, Y\>\\
                   &= \<Y, Z - \lambda \> + \lambda.
  \end{align*}

We can now introduce the dual function

$$
  \begin{aligned}
   q(\lambda) &= \sup_{Y\in [0,\alpha^{-1}]} L(Y,\lambda)\\
              &= \sup_{Y\in [0,\alpha^{-1}]} \<Y, Z - \lambda \> + \lambda\\
              &= \sup_{Y\in [0,\alpha^{-1}]} \int Y(Z-\lambda)\mathrm{dP} + \lambda,
  \end{aligned}
$$
the supremum is attained for $Y=\alpha^{-1}1_{[Z-\lambda\geq 0]}$, so
$$
 q(\lambda) = \alpha^{-1}\mathbb{E}[Z-\lambda]_+ + \lambda.
$$
The dual problem is
  $$
   \inf_{\lambda\in\Re}\ \alpha^{-1}\mathbb{E}[Z-\lambda]_+ + \lambda.
  $$
  The set of its minimizers is a bounded set, so we have strong duality.

Under the above assumptions ($H_X$ being continuous, $\{t: H_X(t)=1-\alpha\}$ being a singleton and for $t^*$ as above), $Y\in\partial \ES_\alpha(X)$ if and only if

$$
\mathbb{E}[Y]=1\\
X>t^* \implies Y = \alpha^{-1}\\
X<t^* \implies Y=0\\
X=t^* \implies Y\in [0,\alpha^{-1}]
$$

Finally, the directional derivative of $\ES_\alpha$ at $X$ along $D$ will be

$$
\ES'_\alpha(X;D) = \sup_{Y\in\partial\ES_\alpha(X)}\<Y,D\>
$$

Comment: Incredible answer! This is exactly what I was looking for